# how to get a string from a specific position in a file through c in ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have stored some website names with their corresponding ip addresses(random) in a text file named 'DNS'. For a particular website name I need to find its corresponding ip address. I tried the following C program. It shows the error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am trying to check if the website is present in the file character by character, if found the read pointer is stopped at the last character of the website. After skipping a character, the rest of the characters are stored in an array called ip. But the same code works fine in windows. When I try in ubuntu it shows the above error.
The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    FILE* ptr = fopen("DNS.txt","r");
    int found=0, i=0;
    char website[20] = "google.com";
    char ip[30];
    char temp;
    while ((temp=fgetc(ptr)) != EOF){
        if (temp == website[i]){
            i++;
            if (i==strlen(website)){
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            i=0;
    }
    
    if (found){
        i=0;
        temp = fgetc(ptr);
    temp=fgetc(ptr);
        while (temp != '\n'){
            ip[i++]=temp;
        temp=fgetc(ptr);
        }
        ip[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s",ip);
    }
    else{
        printf("Ip address not found");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The DNS file looks like

```
google.com-1234.45.6
youtube.com-5738.292.22
github.com-2374.2342.2
```

The file is stored in the same location as the program.

Comment: A few obvious errors: You do not check result of `fopen` for `NULL`. You use `char temp` while `fgetc` returns an `int`. And you must use `int` to be able to detect `EOF` reliably.

Comment: Please use you debugger to see the exact line where the error occurs. While you are at it, you could also look into the variables to find possible reasons.

Comment: I would suggest to not use `fgetc` but `fgets` and read a complete line at once. You don't care about `\n`and start looking for the host name wherever you found first mismatch. That doesn't make much sense. You should skip the rest of the line and start again with next line. `fgets` would help with that issue

Comment: Is your input file named "DNS", or "DNS.txt"?  Check the result of `fopen`.

Comment: yeah, the actual error was with the file name, I changed the file name from 'DNS' to 'DNS.txt' and it worked fine. But in windows the program was able to identify and open the file named just 'DNS', but in ubuntu the program looks for the file which should be named exactly given in fopen().

Answer (score 0):

Given your file format, it would be easier to just slurp in the entire line with `fgets` and then use something like `strtok` or `sscanf` to split it into the name and address fields, then compare the name to the desired name. Bit more straightforward and you're making the standard library do the hard work (which is why it's there).

Incomplete example with no error checking:

```
#define LINE_LENGTH 80 // or whatever your maximum input line length
                       // happens to be
...
char line[LINE_LENGTH+1] = {0}; 

while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, ptr ) )
{
  char ip[LINE_LENGTH+1] = {0};
  char name[LINE_LENGTH+1] = {0};

  if ( sscanf( line, "%[^-]-%[^\n]", name, ip ) == 2 )
  {
    if ( strcmp( name, website ) == 0 )
    {
      printf( "%s", ip );
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

You'll want to add some error checking to handle input lines that are longer than your buffer is sized to hold and similar robustification, but this should steer you in the right direction.